# How Do I Automate Database Schema comparison and Synchronization Process for SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, compare

I am using SQL Compare(from Redgates) to compare Sql server Database schema comparison. And I know how to Synchronize it manually.

Is there any process which I can make.. which automatically compares database1 schema with Database2 schema and make synchronization. And this has to be scheduled weekly once..

Answer (score 2):

You can use xSQL Softwares's [Schema Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_schema_compare/) tool which comes with a command line utility or if you wish to integrate the database schema comparison and synchronization into your own code you can use the [Schema Compare SDK](http://www.xsql.com/products/sdk/sql_server_schema_compare/). The xSQL Schema Compare tool is free for SQL Server Express whereas the SDK is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few ways you could to this:

Custom msbuild script to compile & deploy the database via the Release configuration. A script is generated via the msbuild process and can be executed.

If you are using a CI server (such as CCnet) you can configure the relevant type of task (in CCNet, you configure a msbuild task)

You would also be able to use powershell to call the msbuild funcutions.

[CCNet Config](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/MsBuild_Task)

[MSBuild Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to automate the process by using SQl Scripts?

Comment: yes there is. you would simply change the msbuild params to output the msbuild call to generate a sql file, and then automate the call of this sql script, using a batch file (the best example i can think of) and then use a windows scheduler to automatically run the sql script at a predetermined date/time. you would use the SQLcmd utility to run the script itself. (so you would be calling the sqlcmd utility from within the batch file).

Comment: i dont think you could completely automate the entire process via sql scripts, if that is what you meant, rather than my comment above. some of it would need to be external from sql.

Comment: no, sql is not capabile of generating thescriopts in itself. Also this wont work in general for production databases because many scenarios simply can not be automated.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that SQL Compare Pro has command line tools for continuous integration.  That may be an easy option considering you already have the tool and it should be an easy exercise to automate the command line options.